# How to get twitter trends using python & tweepy, Visualization on top 10 trending topics?

Tags: python, visualization, tweets

> Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

what need to be done to rectify this?

Tried to Develop a Jupyter Notebook which on executing every time shows top 10 Twitter
trending topics in India in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Are you using the v1.1 API (`tweepy.API`) or the v2 API (`tweepy.Client`)?

Comment: api                       0.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi

Comment: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints